# Creating a wxPanel to draw on

Tags: wxwidgets

I am trying to create a wxPanel to paint lines and points on it.

My program consists of the following windows:

1. MyFrame : the default frame class which inherits from wxFrame
2. Final_Layout : an instance of wxPanel with parent MyFrame (i.e. this pointer) , and it contains all of my controls

Now, I am trying to create a new panel, Draw_Panel, that I can draw on it. I would like to append this panel besides Final_Layout using wxBoxSizer.

So, my first step is in initilizing the panel, I have the following code:

```
   void MyFrame::Initialize_Draw_Input() {

    Draw_Panel = new wxPanel(this, -1); // QUESTION : Who is the parent here? Should it be Final_Layout or "this" pointer?
    Draw_Panel ->Connect(wxEVT_PAINT, wxPaintEventHandler(MyFrame::OnPaint));

}

    void MyFrame::OnPaint(wxPaintEvent& event)
    {
        wxPaintDC dc(Draw_Panel );

        wxCoord x1 = 50, y1 = 60;
        wxCoord x2 = 100, y2 = 60;

        dc.DrawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    }
```

However, this does not work. I think I am misunderstanding how wxPanels work... I would appreciate any help / guidance

Edit:

Based on the help below (which I greatly appreciate), I made the following update to the code. However, now I cannot draw on the panel:

```
    void MyFrame::Initialize_Draw_Input() {

    Draw_Panel = new wxPanel(Final_Panel, wxID_ANY,wxDefaultPosition,wxSize(1000,1000),wxTAB_TRAVERSAL,"");
    Draw_StaticBox = new wxStaticBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL, Draw_Panel, _T("Cross Section"));
    Draw_Sizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);

   // Draw_Panel->Connect(wxEVT_PAINT, wxPaintEventHandler(MyFrame::OnPaint), NULL, this);

    wxStaticText* x = new wxStaticText(Draw_Panel,wxID_ANY,"");
    Draw_Sizer->Add(x);
    Draw_StaticBox->Add(Draw_Sizer,wxSizerFlags().Expand());
    Draw_Panel->SetSizer(Draw_StaticBox);

    PaintNow();

}

void MyFrame::PaintNow() {

    wxClientDC dc(Draw_Panel);
    Render(dc);

}

void MyFrame::Render(wxDC& dc) {

    wxCoord x1 = 0, y1 = 60;
    wxCoord x2 = 100, y2 = 60;

    dc.DrawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);

}
```

My constructor:

```
MyFrame::MyFrame() : wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, "Cross Sectional Properties", wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(1500, 600), wxDEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE & ~(wxRESIZE_BORDER | wxMAXIMIZE_BOX)) {

    wxBoxSizer* Element_and_Node_hSizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
    wxBoxSizer* Info_and_Data_Input_vSizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
    wxBoxSizer* Output_and_Draw_vSizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);

    wxBoxSizer* Main_hSizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);


    Final_Panel = new wxPanel(this, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxTAB_TRAVERSAL, _T(""));

    Initialize_ProjectInfo_Input(); //Info_Panel, a wxFrame instance is defined here. It contains a wxGrid and other controls for project info input.
    Initialize_Node_Input();        //Node_Panel,  a wxFrame instance is defined here. It contains a wxGrid control for node data input.
    Initialize_Element_Input();     //Element_Panel,  a wxFrame instance is defined here. It contains a wxGrid control for element data input.
    Initialize_Output();            //Out_Panel, a wxFrame instance defined here. It contians a wxGrid for cross sectional properties output. 
    Initialize_Draw_Input();
    InitMenu();                     //Initializes the menu.


    //Combines the Node and element input wxGrid into one sizer - horizontally
    Element_and_Node_hSizer->Add(Node_Panel, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand().Border(wxBOTTOM | wxLEFT |wxRIGHT));
    Element_and_Node_hSizer->Add(Element_Panel, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand().Border(wxBOTTOM | wxRIGHT));

    //Combines the project input and the (Node & Elemetn Input) into one sizer - vertically
    Info_and_Data_Input_vSizer->Add(Info_Panel, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand().Border(wxALL));
    Info_and_Data_Input_vSizer->Add(Element_and_Node_hSizer,wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());

    //Combines output data and draw panel into one sizer - vertically
    Output_and_Draw_vSizer->Add(Out_Panel,wxSizerFlags(1).Border(wxALL));
    Output_and_Draw_vSizer->Add(Draw_Panel, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand().Border(wxLEFT| wxBOTTOM  | wxRIGHT));

    //Combines all into the final layout
    Main_hSizer->Add(Info_and_Data_Input_vSizer);
    Main_hSizer->Add(Output_and_Draw_vSizer);


    SetSizer(Main_hSizer);

    PaintNow();

}
```

[image]

Also unrelated, would anyone know how to center a wxGrid? the "Coordiates of Nodes" section does not look good.

Comment: Thanks for this very basic example how to draw on a panel! I was a bit lost in the complexity of the drawing example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple issues here.

1. You really should stick with the symbolic constant `wxID_ANY` instead of using -1 in the line

```
Draw_Panel = new wxPanel(this, -1);.
```

That way in the very, very unlikely event that wxID_ANY is changed to something else, your code will continue to work.

---

2. In the line

```
Draw_Panel ->Connect(wxEVT_PAINT, wxPaintEventHandler(MyFrame::OnPaint));
```

you need to supply [2 more parameters](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_evt_handler.html#aa290d9b67348e74c1da8497955a4e35c): userData (which will almost always be `NULL`) and eventSink (which will almost always be `this`). So the line should look like so:

```
Draw_Panel ->Connect(wxEVT_PAINT, wxPaintEventHandler(MyFrame::OnPaint),NULL,this);
```

---

3. You don't show your constructor, so based on previous questions, I assume it looks like this

```
MyFrame::MyFrame...

    Info_Panel = new wxPanel(this, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxTAB_TRAVERSAL, _T(""));
    Initialize_Project_Info();
    Initialize_Draw_Input();
}
```

I'm assuming Final_Layout is what was called Info_Panel in previous questions.  However, you might notice this causes the 2 panels to be drawn on top of each other.  To get around this, add 1 more sizer to MyFrame

```
MyFrame::MyFrame....

    wxBoxSizer* MainSizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
    Info_Panel = new wxPanel(this, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxTAB_TRAVERSAL, _T(""));
    Initialize_Project_Info();
    Initialize_Draw_Input();

    Info_Panel->Fit();
    MainSizer->Add(Info_Panel,wxSizerFlags(0));
    MainSizer->Add(Draw_Panel,wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());

    SetSizer(MainSizer);
}
```

This produces this layout:

[image]

---

4. Notice that ugly rectangle in the lower left. That's the frames background.  To get rid of it, you can add 1 more panel to your class.  I'll call it `framePanel`, but it can be called anything you want.  Then `framePanel` will be the only child of your frame and the other 2 panels will be children of `framePanel`.

So the new constructor could look like this:

```
MyFrame::MyFrame

    wxBoxSizer* MainSizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
    framePanel = new wxPanel(this, wxID_ANY);
    Info_Panel = new wxPanel(framePanel, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxTAB_TRAVERSAL, _T(""));
    Initialize_Project_Info();
    Initialize_Draw_Input();

    Info_Panel->Fit();
    MainSizer->Add(Info_Panel,wxSizerFlags(0));
    MainSizer->Add(Draw_Panel,wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());

    framePanel->SetSizer(MainSizer);
}
```

And you should also change the defition for `Draw_Panel` to have the new parent like this:

```
Draw_Panel = new wxPanel(framePanel, wxID_ANY);
```

Finnally this gives this layout:

[image]

This is why the answer to your previous question included the part

> While you can place controls directly in a wxFrame, because of 'TAB traversal' and a OS's typical background features you better use a wxPanel.

---

5. Based on the edit with the static box around the draw panel, you need to create the static box sizer first and then create the panel as a child of the static box:

```
void MyFrame::Initialize_Draw_Input() {

    Draw_StaticBox = new wxStaticBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL, Final_Panel, _T("Cross Section"));
    Draw_Panel = new wxPanel(Draw_StaticBox->GetStaticBox(), wxID_ANY,wxDefaultPosition,wxSize(1000,1000),wxTAB_TRAVERSAL,"");
    Draw_Sizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);

    Draw_Panel->Connect(wxEVT_PAINT, wxPaintEventHandler(MyFrame::OnPaint), NULL, this);

    wxStaticText* x = new wxStaticText(Draw_StaticBox->GetStaticBox(),wxID_ANY,"");
    Draw_Sizer->Add(x);
    Draw_StaticBox->Add(Draw_Panel,wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());
    Draw_StaticBox->Add(Draw_Sizer,wxSizerFlags().Expand());
}
```

Right now neither `Draw_Sizer` nor the empty static text `x` seem serve any purpose, but I assume they're place holders for something that will come later.

Finally, you need to change the constructor to add `Draw_StaticBox` to `Output_and_Draw_vSizer` instead of `Draw_Panel`.  ie change

```
Output_and_Draw_vSizer->Add(Draw_Panel, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand().Border(wxLEFT| wxBOTTOM  | wxRIGHT));
```

to

```
Output_and_Draw_vSizer->Add(Draw_StaticBox, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand().Border(wxLEFT| wxBOTTOM  | wxRIGHT));
```

Comment: Thank you, I have a better understanding of panels and their interaction with frames

Comment: Hmmmm, I made a few changes to the code by adding a static box sizer around the panel, and now, I can't draw on it. I have attached my code. Do you know why this might be the case? I posted the code in the OP

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, you commented out the Connect call to the paint handler and added code to draw with a client dc.  That will perform the drawing one time but any drawing will be overwritten the next time the panel is refreshed. To make sure the drawing is done every time the panel is refreshed you need use the paint event and draw it with the paint dc.

Comment: The original code you suggested stopped painting the line for some reason, that's why I tried to use wxClientDC instead. But even this control does not paint.

Comment: I see now.  In the code you posted, you created a static box than covers the draw panel.  I think you need to that in the opposite order - create the static box sizer and then create the panel on the static box.  I edited the answer to add item 5 to give an example of how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Usually the paibt events are handled in the appropriare window and not in the parent window.

Anyway, try the following:

```
   void MyFrame::Initialize_Draw_Input()
   {
    Draw_Panel = new wxPanel(this, -1); Should it be Final_Layout or "this" pointer?
    Draw_Panel ->Bind(wxEVT_PAINT, &MyFrame::OnPaint, this);
    }
```

To answer the question - the parent is `this` pointer, i.e. MyFrame instance. Which is correct - you just need to set up the sizer appropriately.

Can you post the sizer code?

Comment: I'm debugging my code further, I can post it once the code runs again lol